# Network state listener using broadcast receiver not working in Android 7.0?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-7.0-nougat

**ERROR:**

```
NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default.
```

Answer (score 1):

yes old method is deprecated you should use this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
   registerReceiver(new ConnectionCheck(), new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
}
```